# Getting the correct dimensions after using np.nonzero on array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes, zero

When using the the np.nonzero on a 1d array:

```
l = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])
np.nonzero(l)
array([1,2,3], dtype=int64)
```

How do I get the index information as a 1d array and not as a tuple in the most effecient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just index the tuple

```
Idn = np.nonzero(l)[0]
```

Code of `flatnonzero` does

```
return a.ravel().nonzero()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.nonzero` will return the index information as a 1d tuple only. However, if you are looking for an alternative,Use `np.argwhere`

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])
non_zero = np.argwhere(l!=0)
```

However, this will return a column matrix. To convert it to a row matrix,

```
non_zero = non_zero.T[0]
```

Comment: I believe `argwhere` does `transpose(nonzero(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`np.flatnonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) for use on a `1D` array -

```
In [5]: l
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])

In [6]: np.flatnonzero(l)
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3])
```